# How do you add command line args to airflow python operator?

Tags: python, airflow, argparse

```
validation = PythonOperator(
    task_id="validation",
    python_callable=validation,
    op_args=[
            "--foo", foo,
            "--bar", "null",

    )
)
```

I'm trying to call a method from the airflow PythonOperator that requires command-line arguments which are accessed using argparse. How do I add these in to the PythonOperator?

I tried the above example but these arguments were invalid. The validation method takes no arguments.

I get this error:

```
ERROR - Failed to execute job 51 for task validation (main() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given; 10436)
[2023-02-17, 19:07:36 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:159}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: If you are trying to use an operator to run as in the command-line you should probably take a look to the [BashOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html). See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42016491). The PythonOperator is intended to run a Python function (a Python _callable_ really) . Sort of how you'd normally run the function if you imported it in another module (erm... as in: `from my_module import my_function` if you know what I mean?)

Comment: Is there anyway to get around using the bash operator to call this? This is in MWAA and this method is from a dependency in `requirements.txt` so I'm not sure what the `path to the code` is and AWS doesn't let you ssh in and see the path of these things.

Comment: Glancing at the PythonOperator docs, I don't see where `argparse` could be relevant.  `argparse` is a tool for parsing command line arguments that bash/python supplies in the `sys.argv` list.  Don't confuse the `argparse` use of `optionals` and `positionals`, with  the  python function use of `positional` and `keyword` arguments.

Comment: I don't know a way (there might be one, but **I** don't know it). Can you check what that `validation::main` does? Do you have access to its code? Because if you're lucky, and it only extracts the arguments with `argparse` and then calls another function, maaaybe you could call that function with the `op_args` (or `op_kwargs` or whatever). Let's say your `main()` only extracts arguments and then calls the function `whatever(arg1, arg2)`, right? If that's the case, then maybe you could use the `PythonOperator` to call `whatever` with `op_args=[arg1, arg2]` rather than `validation`